# How to call the MAPI API IOlkAccountManager::SetOrder successfully

Tags: c++, outlook, mapi

I wrote the following code in my application to set the order for the outlook accounts, but it crashes it. I can see API GetOrder successfully returning all configured accounts details (i.e. 3 accounts and account id), but when the same pointer is passed to SetOrder API, the application crashes with an Access Violation exception.

```
        hResult = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_OlkAccountManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC,
            IID_IOlkAccountManager, (LPVOID *)lpManager.getptr());
        if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
        {
            // this should sync Outlook Accounts with MAPI transports
            LOG_ADDIN(_T("Forcing Outlook accounts syncronization with new personas data"));
            hResult = lpManager->Init(&accHelper, OLK_ACCOUNT_NO_FLAGS);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hResult))
            {
                DWORD *piAccount = new DWORD;
                DWORD **piAccounts = new DWORD*[*piAccount];
                hResult = lpManager->GetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, piAccount, piAccounts);
                hResult = lpManager->SetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, piAccount, piAccounts);
    }
     }
```

**Any assistance is greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

`GetOrder` takes a pointer to `DWORD` as the second parameter (count) and a pointer to a pointer to an array of DWORDs as the third parameter (you are supposed to free it using `IOlkAccountManager.FreeMemory`).

`SetOrder` takes a DWORD as the second parameter (not a pointer!), and a pointer to an array of DWORDs.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response. I'm not sure why I passed the pointer there. I corrected the code as shown below, but it still crashes. (i have 3 mail accounts)  =>                     DWORD piAccount;
                    DWORD *piAccounts = new DWORD[3];
                    hResult = lpManager->GetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, &piAccount, &piAccounts);
                    hResult = lpManager->SetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, &piAccount, &piAccounts);
                    lpManager->FreeMemory((BYTE*)piAccounts);

Comment: It is still wrong - the arguments when you call GetOrder and SetOrder are still the same in your code. `lpManager->SetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, piAccount, piAccounts);`

Comment: Corrected code as below: DWORD *d = new DWORD(3);
                    DWORD *ss = new DWORD[3];
                    ss[0] = piAccounts[0];
                    ss[1] = piAccounts[1];
                    ss[2] = piAccounts[2];
                    hResult = lpManager->SetOrder(&CLSID_OlkMail, d, &ss);                                                        still getting exception: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF88A01A3C7 (OLMAPI32.DLL) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000006907200000.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Now getting error: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF888E3A3C7 (OLMAPI32.DLL) in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000138B203000). Can you please tell me the way to pass the parameters i have 3 mail accounts configured.

Comment: You don't need to create a new DWORD - just pass a pointer (&) to an existing DWORD variable. No reason to allocate an array DWORDs - GetOrder will return a newly allocated array (you must free it using IOlkAccountManager.FreeMemory

Comment: And once again, the second argument in SetOrder is DWORD, not DWORD*. The third argument is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for reply it resolved my issue. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: If the reply answer your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!